# tinyMCE - is it possible to prevent the cut and paste of images (base64) in the textbox?

Tags: tinymce

TinyMCE 4:  I have implemented the image file/upload from local source, using php to save the uploaded file into a directory, with tinyMCE referencing this image. Works fine.  This leaves a simple html text file to save in the database.

However, I see that the user can just cut and paste an image directly into the textbox, resulting in the image showing up and becoming a base64 image string, which defeats the purpose of storing only html text.  Now the text could become extremely long if this base64 image is not prevented.

Is there a way to prevent this image paste action in tinyMCE?  Or better yet, a way to automatically convert this paste into an image file and have it stored in the same place as the other images on the fly?

I know I could convert base64 images to a jpg files and store after submitting the form to a php handler, but would seek a simpler answer if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is your friend for this issue.  TinyMCE can certainly help you convert the images on the fly as they are pasted into the editor:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/handle-async-image-uploads/

You can also stop the images from appearing in the first place if that is your preference:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_data_images

Comment: The first reference doesn

Comment: I added, `paste_data_images: false,` to the configuration, but it still allowed me to paste images into the textarea.

Comment: The async image uploads page per your suggested link seems to say you can paste images and have the system save it to a directory as a file.  However, could not find a good example of this.  All the examples are for uploading images and storing them which I am already doing.  However pasting an image results in a base64 string, which it does not say how to convert that on the fly...  Still too much of a newbie to figure it out.

Comment: They broke all the old links on their website.  How worthless of an update.  Just had to go with that SPA didn't they?